# Single-spa background loading of child application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have Single-Spa micro frontend setup with Dynamic Module Loading in React.

The current user journey looks like below
Root Application -> Authentication Application -> User Enters Details -> API Call -> Redirect ->Admin Application

I want to know if it's possible to load the application in the background when the user is entering credentials(some interaction).

If I can load the application in the background then the user won't have to wait for the admin application to load and the user experience would be much better.

Thanks

I've tried to look into official docs and on the interent but couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try system.import('<your-application>'), by placing a hook to identify user interaction on your credentials input.

Single-spa will look into the import-map and load the application and will be ready to mount as you redirect.